# How to set 3rd party cookies from an iframe in Safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I have an app that only works as an iframe inside a window. I have no control over the parent window domain and no way of knowing ahead of time what those domains could be. The app needs to set cookies in order to manage sessions. However, in Safari 13, the app is unable to set cookies since it is a 3rd party context and it's blocked by ITP.

I have tried redirecting the user to a window on the apps domain so it can at a cookie there but the app is still unable to set a cookie inside the iframe. I have tried requesting access to the Storage API but even then the app does not get the ability to set 3rd party cookies.

Is there any solution even if it requires manual intervention from the user e.g. asking them to change some settings, prompting some action, etc?

Comment: Would you be averse to having the user install a JS injector like TamperMonkey?

Comment: Yes, asking users to install stuff would probably be a bridge too far